# Seeking clarification on Spring Boot 'End Of Support' policy

Tags: spring-boot

I have a confusion in understanding Spring Boot 'End of support' policy.

**Problem statement:**

As per https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support, the support page says 3.0.x has End of Support (EOS) as 2023-11-24.

However, the details from https://tanzu.vmware.com/support/oss says as follows

1. Open Source Community Project Major Releases will be supported for up to 3 years from the date such Release was made available for purchase and download by customers.
2. Open Source Community Project Minor Releases will be supported a minimum of 12 months from the date such Release was made available for purchase and download by customers.
3. Open Source Spring Community Project Minor releases will be supported a minimum of 24 months from the date such release is made available for download and support as part of product subscription purchase.

**Question**

My question here is, what is the actual EOS for Spring Boot version. If I go by the points mentioned above, I should get more than 1 year of support time from the time the inital release was made. For example, V3 is a major release and I expect it to stay supported for 3 years as per point #1.

I see a discrepancy between what I is mentioned as EOS and what is stated in the policy. May be, I am missing or misunderstanding.

Please clarify...

TIA,
-Prem

Answer (score 0):

Yes you miss understood.
Let me explain a bit how it work.
According to [Support Part](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) that you gave and also [VmWare Suport](https://tanzu.vmware.com/support/oss)

`Spring Boot` major version is `3.x` it will have an support for 3 years.

And minor version is that `x` after `.` as example `3.1` `3.2` and so one these versions of framework will have one year of support.